# squid + iptables not working

Tags: proxy, iptables, squid

I would like to setup a proxy on my ubuntu VM to test a PHP script that must use a proxy.
I installed Squid and made some things with iptables command.

I wrote :

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Then I edited my squid.conf file :

```
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
#
acl localnet src 192.168.152.132/24 #this is my ip address
#
acl SSL_ports port 443      # https
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all

http_port 3128 transparent

visible_hostname MyProxy

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

so every port 80 request are now blocked and in Firefox when I'm editing my proxy settings I would like to pass through that proxy. I wrote my ip address with squid's port but I still get an access denied error. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, it's not quite clear to me, what you set up in Firefox. Can you describe more in detail what you did and what happened?

Comment: I wonder why you're blocking port 80? There's an option on squid to do it transparently but this doesn't work best for https. Though, if you're only testing your scripts, I would assume transparent proxy will still work for that setup.

Answer (score -2):

From the terminal run:

```
sudo squid3 -k reconfigure
```

`-k reconfigure` - Parse configuration file, then send signal to running copy and exit

Comment: Please explain what that does.

Comment: Someone's trying to jump into conclusion without probing. Not really helping at all.